# How to create route-less substates in an ember.js 1.6.x

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, url-routing

I would like to create something like an admin sub-application that is available on every page of my existing ember 1.6.x app. It will have it's own state-machine (router) allowing it to load different controllers/templates depending on it's own state. I have seen a lot of similar discussions that revolve around having multiple state machines (routers) or extensive use of sub-routes but nothing really hit's the nail on the head.

Is there a clear way to create what is in effect two ember apps on the same page?

The sub-app does not need to actually have routes that are interpreted in the url bar. It also does not need to have it's state maintained when the parent app changes routes/states. It can be reset every time the parent app changes to a different route. What I want to avoid is repeating the same code over and over again inside multiple controllers in the parent app. I would also like to avoid polluting the application or global levels.

Below is a list of discussions that I have looked into. The closest thing that I can find that makes sense is the work on ember flows (which has not been finished yet). Or should I literally be looking into creating a new state-machine via the ember-states plugin for the sub-app?

To be clear I am not looking for someone to write the code for me. Just a discussion on how this SHOULD be done with ember 1.6.x as it is currently available.

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/route-less-substates/2269

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/is-there-a-reason-we-can-not-have-nested-routes/1845

[Sending action to Ember.StateManager : is goToState mandatory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10688436/sending-action-to-ember-statemanager-is-gotostate-mandatory)

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/406

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/4767

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/concurrent-states-in-ember/5042

https://github.com/nathanhammond/ember-flows-generator

https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/406#issuecomment-3702356

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run multiple embedded isolated Ember apps inside another Ember app.

An embedded Ember app can manipulate URL state like any other app or you can configure it to *have* **routing states** but not interact with URL.

Take a look at [embedding applications documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/configuring-ember/embedding-applications/).

Excerpt:

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  rootElement: '#app'
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: 'none' // To disable manipulating URL
});
```

You can also share code between apps. For example to share an Ember Data model.

```
var MainApp     = Ember.Application.create({});
var AdminApp    = Ember.Application.create({rootElement: '#admin-container'});

AdminApp.Router = Ember.Router.extend({location: 'none'});

MainApp.User    = DS.Model.extend({});
AdminApp.User   = MainApp.User;
```

Comment: I never ended up using any of these answers but this one is the only one that actually would work at that time. If anyone has any idea as to how to get this to work in today's ember ecosystem please post!

Comment: I should add that I didn't go this route because I needed much of the app's internals to be shared. Having 2 separate apps while it would create two separate routers was a little too overkill for my use case. I ended up creating all of the "sub-routes" on the main catchall application route. Ugly but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This could be what you are looking for:

https://github.com/tildeio/conductor.js

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use query-params i did not get your use case completely but checkout this http://instructure.github.io/ic-tabs/query-params.html#/?country=2&food=2